# Is this grammar LR(1)?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, lr-k

A bit confused about whether this grammar is ambiguous or not

```
C' -> C
C -> d C u C
C -> d C
C -> ε
```

I tried building the DFA for this but I get this in one of the states:

```
C -> d C DOT u C, $
    C -> d C DOT, $
```

Isn't this a shift-reduce conflict, so surely it means the grammar is not LR(1)? Or does it reduce regardless since $ and u are both in the follow set of C? Is this not a reduce-reduce conflict since it goes to C regardless?

Comment: Is your question about being LR(1)  or about being ambiguous. A CF grammar may be unambiguous, but not LR(1).

Answer (score 1):

This grammar (which isn't ambiguous) isn't LR(k) due to the right-recursion, thus it isn't LR(1).